# Kubernetes API server and Kubelet communication

Tags: kubernetes

The IP address of API server is at 172.0.1.1.

When the API server address communicates with the Kubelet 10250 port, it always reports an error:

`E0402 03:27:12.970501       1 upgradeaware.go:310] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 172.0.1.1:40190->172.0.128.204:10250: write: broken pipe
E0402 03:27:13.272704       1 upgradeaware.go:310] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 172.0.1.1:33676->172.0.128.243:10250: write: broken pipe
E0402 03:27:14.476613       1 upgradeaware.go:310] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 172.0.1.1:36802->172.0.128.31:10250: write: broken pipe`

I have tried to modify the following parameters:

`Net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time =600
Net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 30
Net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 10`

And execute `sysctl -p` to make it work, but it doesn't solve the problem, or see many of these errors.

Comment: What is a kubelet version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

That was a known issue of the  kubelet keeps connection alive and not bring them down when the corresponding kubectl command was killed.

**Fix** is to upgrade kubelet to version containing [#67288](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/67288), which should now be in all releases **1.10+**, or to periodically restart the kubelet.